# Cypher Assistance, combine two Optional Match with a Match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to have a Cypher like,

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a1:Article) WHERE a1.status='active'
WITH collect(a1) as a1_col
OPTIONAL MATCH (a2:Article) WHERE a2.category='xyz'
WITH DISTINCT a1_col + collect(a2) as a
MATCH (a)-[:author]->(u:User)
WHERE NOT id(u)=101
RETURN a
```

I am getting `Type mismatch: a already defined with conflicting type List<Node>` error with this cypher, any help with this would be much appreciated. I need OPTIONAL_MATCH and MATCH clauses separate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `a` is a `List<Node>`, and you use it inside the `MATCH` clause as a `Node`.

You should use this query instead :

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a1:Article) WHERE a1.status='active'
WITH collect(a1) as a1_col
OPTIONAL MATCH (a2:Article) WHERE a2.category='xyz'
WITH DISTINCT a1_col + collect(a2) as a
MATCH (article)-[:author]->(u:User)
WHERE NOT id(u)=101 AND article IN a
RETURN a
```

I think you can optimize your query like this :

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE id(u)=101 WITH u
MATCH (a:Article)
WHERE (a.category='xyz' OR a.status='active') AND
      NOT (a)-[:author]->(u)
RETURN collect(DISTINCT a)
```

Comment: Thanks @logisima This works, optimised it to `MATCH (article:Article)`
This sill matches all articles, is there a way to match only `a` from above